# Android How to find usable display area

Tags: android

i am trying to find the usable display area in my app so i can size things programmatically. i have the following so far

```
    @Override 
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(metrics);
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);


        final TypedArray styledAttributes = getBaseContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                new int[] { android.R.attr.actionBarSize });
        int actionBarHeight = (int) styledAttributes.getDimension(0, 0);
        styledAttributes.recycle();

        int usableHeight = size.y - actionBarHeight;
```

which works in most cases but i have a tablet that is set up with a menu bar on top (32 pixels high), that contains the time, network status, battery level etc (don't know if there is a real name for that) and a bar at the bottom (48 pixels high) which has the back button, apps key and screen shot button.

my device is 800x600 so when i do display.getSize(size); i get 552 = 600 - bottom bar of 48 pixels. the problem is, it doesn't subtract the top bar.

so how do i access that top bar (if it exists) so i can find the true application area?

i have another tablet where the time, battery level and wifi status are on the same bar as the back button, apps button, screen shot, etc so no problem with that one.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the screen area available for your app you'll need to measure 
the parent view of your own app:

```
   final View view = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

   int scrLoc[] = new int[2];
   top.getLocationOnScreen(scrLoc);
   int BottomLoc[] = new int[2];
   bottom.getLocationOnScreen(BottomLoc);
   boolean portrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
   if (portrait) {
      availableWidth = top.getWidth();
      availableHeight = BottomLoc[1] - scrLoc[1];
   } else {
      availableWidth = top.getWidth();
      availableHeight = BottomLoc[1] - scrLoc[1];
   }
```

And, if you need the measurements before onResume (say at onCreate) you will
need to wrap this code within a [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) callback

Finally - if your app is screen-dimension sensitive you probably also want to change its 
internal state when switching screen orientation. To do that

in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation">
```

and within the activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);      
    // your change orientation logic here
}
```

Comment: wow, that's a lot more than i expected. i need to do this before the the screen is rendered, in onCreateOptionsMenu is the best place for me. how would i put it in there? thanks.

Comment: hi, in this example, how do you initialize top and bottom? thanks